# How can I distribute perl modules with my script?

Tags: perl, module, distribution, distribute

And is it good idea? I wrote a script and it uses some unpopular modules. Installing them takes much time, so I thought it would be better to distribute them with my application. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

It is customary to ship dependencies in the `inc` directory of your distribution. I have talked about this in [how do I link PerlIO Perl package without "installing it"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066955/how-do-i-link-perlio-perl-package-without-installing-it) and [automatically install missing modules from CPAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183293/automatically-install-missing-modules-from-cpan) before.

The question is vague, so instead of code, just advice: I make the assumption you want no installation at all. Put the unpacked dependencies in into the `inc` directory. Access it at runtime with [`use lib 'inc';`](http://p3rl.org/lib).

That's all.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Under the Apache license, you can redistribute the modules.

Are these object oriented modules that don't import any functions? Then, you don't have to do anything. Simply remove the `use My::Module;` from the main program, then append `My::Module` right to the end of your main program.

If you are not using object oriented code, and it's exporting functions via the `@EXPORT` array, you'll have to take some additional measures:

Here, I had to add `Local::Foo->import qw(foo)` to import the `foo` function into the main program **even though it's exported via `@EXPORT` and not `@EXPORT_OK`**. I also had to use the BEGIN around my export declarations in my module. Otherwise, my main program would find nothing to import:

Original Programs:

### Main Program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# test.pl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Local::Foo;

use feature qw(say);

my $bar = foo("bar");

say "Bar is '$bar'";
```

### Module Local::Foo

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# Local/Foo.pm
#
package Local::Foo;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT = qw(foo);

sub foo {
    my $value = shift;
    return "FOOOOOO $value";
}
1;
```

### The Combined Program

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# test.pl

use warnings;
use strict;
# use Local::Foo;

# Force importation of `foo`

Local::Foo->import qw(foo);

use feature qw(say);

my $bar = foo("bar");

say "Bar is '$bar'";

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# Local/Foo.pm
#
package Local::Foo;

# Add BEGIN clause to module

BEGIN {
    use Exporter qw(import);
    our @EXPORT = qw(foo);
}

sub foo {
    my $value = shift;
    return "FOOOOOO $value";
}
1;
```

Comment: Who said anything about Apache? (The vast majority of Perl modules are GPL1/Artistic1 dual-licensed, a.k.a. "under the same terms as Perl itself".) - I am not happy with that manual combining, you should recommend fatpacker instead.

Comment: @daxim I don't know anything about _fatpacker_. I found App::Fatpacker. Is that it? There's not much in the way of documentation. Can you provide an answer that explains how to use fatpacker? I would be interested in that.